# Plotly scatter: Change Interval length

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

Need to change the Interval length of x axis from 10 to 7.

[image]

```
fig = px.scatter(df_2020_herb, 
                #  x = "ssn_start_utc",
                 x="PastTime", 
                 y="fld_id", 
                 color="Productname", 
                 hover_data=["name"], 
                 
                 )
fig.show()
```

I can't seem to find arguments to change it in the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter). What should I do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have simulated your data
- [tick formatting](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#tickmode--linear) demonstrated below

```
df_2020_herb = pd.DataFrame({"PastTime":np.random.randint(-70,10,30),
                            "fld_id":np.random.randint(1,12,30),
                            "Productname":["Tillage"]*30}).assign(name=lambda d: d["Productname"])

fig = px.scatter(df_2020_herb, 
                #  x = "ssn_start_utc",
                 x="PastTime", 
                 y="fld_id", 
                 color="Productname", 
                 hover_data=["name"], 
                 
                 )

fig.update_layout(xaxis={"tickmode":"linear","dtick":7})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the xticks in the layout, and use a linear `tickmode` with the `dtick` set to 7. The documentation is [here](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#tickmode--linear)

```
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'linear',
        tick0 = -60,
        dtick = 7
    )
)
```

Comment: Adding tick0 argument equal to 60 or a non-multiple of 7  is messing with the interval. It gets rectified by removing it